# Invalid template property cloud formation for ecr

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecr, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

Hello anyone can help with this invalid template property .
I am trying to create an ECR repo with name as "sample ", with kms.
But is throwing error invalid template property " ImageRepoName."

Any reference to a ECR cloudformation is also fine . ECRRepoName is declared in the parameter section

```
  EcrMlPlatform:
    Type: 'AWS::ECR::Repository'
    Properties:
      DisplayName: !Ref ECRRepoName
      KmsMasterKeyId: !Ref ECRkeyMLPlatform
      EmptyOnDelete: true
      EncryptionConfiguration:
        EncryptionType: KMS
        KmsKey: !Ref ECRkeyMLPlatform
      ImageScanningConfiguration:
        scanOnPush: true
      ImageTagMutability: IMMUTABLE
      RepositoryName: !Ref ECRRepoName
      RepositoryPolicyText:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          -
            Sid: AllowPull
            Effect: Allow
            Principal: "*"
            Action:
              - "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer"
              - "ecr:BatchGetImage"
              - "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability"
              - "ecr:DescribeImages"
              - "ecr:DescribeRepositories"
     

  Outputs:
    ImageRepoName:
     Value: !Sub ${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${ECRRepoName}
```

Comment: consider using validation to check your template `aws cloudformation validate-template`

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved by placing the outputs section as same level of resources. it was a yaml error